# How to extract Breadcrumb data on Expedia flights page by using Excel/ VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have done my research but as I don't have much coding background, it is still hard for me to work out how to do it!

Basically, I have a list of URLs that I would like to scrape the Breadcrumb data on the page. With the information, I can then quickly figure out which city, countries these page are about.

[example of Breadcrumbs on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySlv1.png)

This page:https://www.expedia.co.uk/Cheap-Flights-To-Las-Vegas.d178276.Travel-Guide-Flights
for example, I can see the HTML code for breadcrumbs is as below. How can I extract this info by using excel?

Thanks for your help! much appreciated!

```html
<div class="container  ">
                    <div class="site-content-wrap grid-container cf">
<div class="uitk-col uitk-layout all-col-1-1 desktop-col-1-1 tablet-col-1-1 smalltablet-col-1-1 mobile-col-1-1" data-fm="968204">
    <hr class="separator simple"  id="separator-1" />
<div class="flex-module breadcrumbs default-view" id="breadcrumbs-1" data-fm="968206" data-fm-title-id="">
    <nav class="bread-crumb cf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
        <ol aria-label="breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
                    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                        <a href="/" itemprop="item" data-flex-analytics="flight.TRAVEL_GUIDE_FLIGHTS.Breadcrumbs" data-flex-events="event151"><span itemprop="name">Expedia.co.uk</span></a><span aria-hidden="true" class="separator">&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;</span>
                        <meta itemprop="url" content="/" />
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
                    </li>
                    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                        <a href="/Flights" itemprop="item" data-flex-analytics="flight.TRAVEL_GUIDE_FLIGHTS.Breadcrumbs" data-flex-events="event151"><span itemprop="name">Flights</span></a><span aria-hidden="true" class="separator">&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;</span>
                        <meta itemprop="url" content="/Flights" />
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
                    </li>
                    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                        <a href="/Destinations-In-United-States-Of-America.d201.Flight-Destinations" itemprop="item" data-flex-analytics="flight.TRAVEL_GUIDE_FLIGHTS.Breadcrumbs" data-flex-events="event151"><span itemprop="name">United States of America</span></a><span aria-hidden="true" class="separator">&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;</span>
                        <meta itemprop="url" content="/Destinations-In-United-States-Of-America.d201.Flight-Destinations" />
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="3" />
                    </li>
                    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                        <a href="/Destinations-In-Nevada.d230.Flight-Destinations" itemprop="item" data-flex-analytics="flight.TRAVEL_GUIDE_FLIGHTS.Breadcrumbs" data-flex-events="event151"><span itemprop="name">Nevada</span></a><span aria-hidden="true" class="separator">&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;</span>
                        <meta itemprop="url" content="/Destinations-In-Nevada.d230.Flight-Destinations" />
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="4" />
                    </li>
                            <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                                <strong aria-hidden="true" itemprop="name">Flights to Las Vegas</strong>
                                <strong class="visuallyhidden">
                                    Flights to Las Vegas, current page
                                </strong>
                                <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.expedia.co.uk/Cheap-Flights-To-Las-Vegas.d178276.Travel-Guide-Flights" />
                            </li>
    </ol>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: So are your crumbs in the link:  the info under Cheap round-trip flights to Las Vegas ? Is there a standard way to identify this across pages? What data are you expecting to extract from the link shared?

Comment: In the `bread-crumb cf` class, you just need to extract each `li` value.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I only need the text of the breadcrumb links. Like:
Expedia.co.uk •  Flights •  United States of America •  Nevada •  Flights to Las Vegas

I have tried IMPORTXML with XPATH but doesn't work. I also looked up some VBA tutorial videos on youtube but I had no clue which element should I look at :(((